# Find the inverse of $xe^{1-2x^2}$, $x\geqslant1$

Tags: functions, inverse-function

> Find the inverse of $xe^{1-2x^2}$, $x\geqslant1$

This question is killing me and this is my last resort. Thank you in advance I've found great help on here before.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please check that the edit is correct.

Comment: This function is not bijective (on it's domain), and thus has no inverse.

Comment: Ok there was no domain in the question but if I were to add one as above?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

$$y=xe^{1-2x^2}$$
$-4x^2e^{-4x^2}= -4y^2e^{-2}\quad\to\quad We^W=X\quad \begin{cases} 
W=-4x^2 \\
X=-4y^2e^{-2}
\end{cases}$

A closed form requires the special function $W(X)$ namely the Lambert W-function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html
$$-4x^2=W(-4y^2e^{-2})$$
$$x=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-W(-4y^2e^{-2})}$$
$x(y)$ isn't bijective on the whole range. But if the range is limited to $x\geq \frac{1}{2}$ the relationship is one-to-one :
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-W_{-1}( -4y^2e^{-2} )}$$
where $W_{-1}$ denotes the negative branch of the Lambert W-function, where $W_{-1}(X)<-1$ on the range $-e^{-1}<X<0$

$ -e^{-1}<-4y^2e^{-2}<0 \quad\to\quad 0<y<\frac{\sqrt{e}}{2}$